# Filling in missing values for time series data

Tags: time-series, missing-data

Suppose I have time series data. So 200 cells of data with each row representing a millisecond - although some rows skip certain milliseconds. For example, it goes from 6:22:37 PM to 6:22:39 PM to 6:22:42 PM. Should I fill in the missing millisecond data with their corresponding millisecond and then average the dependent variables and fill in that row?  Or just leave it as it is?

Comment: Could you also interpolate along that dimension to put them all in the same time steps?

Comment: what do you mean by that? Insert previous values into the milliseconds between that?